# Installed Tornado and Python but Apache is still handling .py files

Tags: python, apache, webserver, tornado

How do I get Tornado (or in general another server) to handle the .py files on my host, while Apache still handles the php files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always configured my python scripts inside apache with mod_wsgi. I believe there's no way to relegate to a different server the execution of some domain/filetype. Still, you can make a script to execute whenever an url is called.

You can do it in python an call it with mod_wsgi -> [wsgi docs](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Learn_WSGI)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) and Tornado's [WSGI handler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation#wsgi-and-google-appengine), if you don't mind losing the asynchronous features of Tornado, or you can run your Tornado app and [proxy to it with Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse). In either case you probably don't want each Python file to be executed individually, the way PHP files often are.

As to in general another server, that's pretty broad, but if it's a Python app it probably implements WSGI, otherwise you'll need to proxy to it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have Apache as the web head and Tornado running behind it? Why not just use ProxyPass from port 80 to whatever port Tornado is running on.

You can't get Tornado to serve the .py files like PHP can do with .php files.